# Cache two sets of nodes

Tags: blocks, caching

I have a website where I have some blocks that have one content on all nodes, but different content on nodes with certain NID.

Right now, I have condition in block template based on node ID and blocks have route cache context and node id tags and this works perfectly.

However, this makes a new block cache entry for every NID/route, but in fact, there are only two block variants.

How would one optimize this in the most drupal-ish way so there are only two variants of the block cached?

Comment: The route context is most likely causing it to vary by route. You'll have to provide your own `cache.context`-tagged service so you can customize how Drupal makes cache variations of that block based on your own custom logic.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, the solution to this problem is to provide its own cache context that checks if the current node id matches a list of nodes, and returns a different context string if this is true or not.

Then use this cache context on own block.